# UITableViewCell disorder when reloading rows to expand and shrink

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm facing a crazy issue which is about expanding and shrinking UITableViewCell. When I click just one cell it works properly but while one cell remains open, clicking another cell to open causes the cell disorder. I would want to expand and shrink at the same time.

Here is my source.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Add items
    [listOfItems addObject:@"1"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"2"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"3"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"4"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"5"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"6"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"7"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"8"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [listOfItems count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel *aLabel;     UILabel *bLabel; UILabel *v1Label;  UILabel *v2Label;; UIView *v1;  UIView *v2;  


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@" cell null");
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        aLabel                      = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9.0, 8.0, 50.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
        aLabel.tag                  = 1;
        aLabel.font                 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aLabel];


        v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 116)];
        v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor  redColor];
        v1.tag = 10;
        v1.hidden = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:v1];
        [v1 release];     


        v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 100)];
        v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor  blueColor];
        v2.tag = 11;
        v2.hidden = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:v2];
        [v2 release];     

    }

    else  {
            aLabel =  (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

            v1     =  (UIView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];          
            v2     =  (UIView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];     
    }

    aLabel.text = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (SelectedIndexPath == indexPath.row) 
        {       
            if ([aLabel.text intValue] %  2) {
                v1.hidden = NO;
                v2.hidden = YES;
            }
            else  {
                v1.hidden = YES;
                v2.hidden = NO;
            }
        }
        else {
            v1.hidden = YES;
            v2.hidden = YES;
            }

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (SelectedIndexPath == indexPath.row)  
    {
        return 100.0;
    }
    else {
        return 46.0;
    }

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (SelectedIndexPath == -1)
    {
        OldSelectedIndexPath = indexPath.row;
        SelectedIndexPath = indexPath.row;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:NO];
    }
    else 
    {
        if (SelectedIndexPath == indexPath.row) 
        {
            OldSelectedIndexPath = SelectedIndexPath;
            SelectedIndexPath = -1;

            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:NO];

        }
        else 
        {
            SelectedIndexPath = indexPath.row;

            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:OldSelectedIndexPath inSection:indexPath.section], indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:NO];

            OldSelectedIndexPath = SelectedIndexPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the facth that your cell will have a height of 160.0 when selected.

Look here

> v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 116)];

You give an heigh of 116 to a view which y origin is 44. Thus your cell view will have a total height of 160.0

Change the value returned in

> -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

To match the correct total height of your cell.

Comment: Also notice that the height will vary depending on the row value as v1 and v2 don't have the same height.

Comment: view height does not seem to cause as my actual source code is 160. I guess the problem is that if reuse the cell, reloadrowindexpat work weird. But if does not use cell identifier,  everything works perfect.

Comment: In your code the height return was 100.0 in tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: If you doubt about reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: i invite you to try reloadData at least for testing purpose. But as i created a project with your code and returning 160.0 was working fine, i don't see what else wouldn't work...

Comment: Thats correct. My problem was that I used duplicated tag value. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Or may be the problem is due to releasing. anything is going to release and you are still using it.

first comment // all release and inter prate your

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`